# Kubernetes pod can't communicate with other pods in the same node

Tags: kubernetes, istio

We are using Kubernetes 1.21.7 , Istio 1.11.4 , Flannel 0.14.0 .

```
kubectl get nodes
NAME     STATUS   ROLES                  AGE    VERSION
k8s-d0   Ready    control-plane,master   204d   v1.21.7
k8s-d1   Ready    <none>                 204d   v1.21.7
k8s-d2   Ready    <none>                 204d   v1.21.7
```

If pod-a and pod-b are in the same node, for example k8s-d1, they can't communicate (using curl for example). But if I force pods to be in different nodes, they communicate just fine.
This issue only occurs in "istio-system" namespace, but it seems it is not an Istio bug (I already tried opening an issue [here](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/36050) , but unsuccessful)

Comment: Have you tried without istio?

Comment: Nobody can help with the amount of information you have provided

Comment: You need to provide more details to make your problem [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please answer my questions:  how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud providor? Please provide also your yaml files and logs from pods/nodes. When exactly did the problem appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what was missing:

```
modprobe br_netfilter
echo "br_netfilter" >> /etc/modules-load.d/modules.conf
```

At same point, I restarted those nodes and br_netfilter didn't load up automatically. Now that it is written in  /etc/modules-load.d/modules.conf , it does apply on boot.

Thank you for your support.